# Lua syntax highlighting in KDevelop

Tags: lua, syntax-highlighting, kdevelop

Does anyone know how to fix the Lua syntax highlighting in Kdevelop.  The # symbol used to get the length of a table causes the remainder of the line to appear as if it is commented out.

t[*#t+1] = "foo"*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Lua so I can't give you specific code, but to fix the highlighting you'd have to edit the KatePart Lua syntax highlighting file, located at $KDEDIR/share/apps/katepart/syntax/lua.xml (on my system $KDEDIR is /usr/kde/3.5). You can find a description of the XML format at http://kate-editor.org/article/writing_a_kate_highlighting_xml_file... they're not the clearest directions but I haven't found anything else equivalent. Thankfully there are plenty of examples included with KDE.